# Shopify Webhooks to Laravel Route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, shopify, webhooks

I'm in need of some help gather the JSON send by Shopify within Laravel ...

```
Route::post('/shopify/webhook/payment', function() {

    // capture json here

});
```

How does one capture the JSON from the webhook? Should I be using `fopen('php://input');` or is there a better way through Laravel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From reading the [Shopify documentation](http://docs.shopify.com/api/tutorials/using-webhooks#receive-webhook), it appears that the webhook `POST`s JSON directly in the body (not in a variable). So yes, under normal circumstances you'd use `file_get_contents('php://input')` and then `json_decode` that.

However, Symfony's bootup actually reads this stream, rendering it useless to you (this stream can only be read once in PHP). <del>As such, you have to read the POST body from the Symfony Request object: `$json = json_decode(Request::getContent());`</del>

Actually Laravel helps you out even more: just do `$json = Request::json();` That will get you the whole JSON as a Laravel `ParameterBag`, or you can pass a key (and its default) in: `$something = Request::json('key', 'default value');`

Comment: Do you know if it's a POST, PUT or GET? I don't think my Route is responding correctly...

Comment: @dcolumbus the docs say it's a POST. See the 'receive a webhook' part of the page linked to in my answer.

Comment: But to test, you could specify the route without specifying its method: `Route::any('route/name', function () { /* logic here */ });`

Answer (score 1):

I created my helper function, which will fetch json, and send with reponse:

```
public function getJson($path,$type,$response)
    {
        if($type == "decoded"){
            return $this->decode(\File::get($path),$response);

        }
            return $this->encode(\File::get($path),$response);
    }
```

decode and encode are just abstractions over **json_encode** and **json_decode** functions. Response flag indicated if json should be sent as HTTP response, or plain text. File is Laravel wrapper around builtin PHP file handling.

Comment: So the Shopify hook passes 3 params? I wonder why I couldn't find that anywhere in their documentation ... this is the problem with these big companies, they always skip the most basic things and assume that everyone will get it.

Comment: @dcolumbus I'm not sure carousel's answer actually has anything to do with Shopify, and is more about generally marshalling JSON from a given uploaded file (though I'm not sure of why this method is required as there's no explanation or context given), so I don't think, therefore, you'll find anything relating to this in their documentation.